# Java virtual heap space

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, virtual-memory

My application has a feature that generates images(jpg) , it uses a lot of heap space (more then allowed on host server). Is their any way i can make it to use less heap memory. I mean, just like our Computers uses virtual memory when RAM is full. Is their any way for java to use external memory as virtual heap space ?

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_memory#Secondary_storage

Comment: any memory that java can use as a virtual heap ..
it may be RAM , Secondary memory.. etc..

Comment: Looks like you should try to improve your algorithm.

Comment: @tuğrul büyükışık: JPG is already compressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically speaking, no. That's up to the OS (check Michael Wiles answer).

Broadly speaking, yes: once you generate a JPG and it's no longer **immediately** used, write it to disk and destroy the object representing it (holding its data). This is slower, but will use less RAM.

Comment: but that image generation alone takes to much memory.... i already tried what you suggested..

Comment: Must be a **HUGE** JPG then, or you're doing something wrong... Anyway same idea still applies: do the image generation in parts, and write each part to disk instead of having all of it in RAM. Once finished, assemble the parts.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the java app with -Xmx4g or something. This will allow the java vm to use 4 gigs of ram regardless of how much ram the system has. When the java VM asks for more memory than RAM is available the host OS will provide the memory as virtual memory.

Comment: i don't mean that ..... i want to vitualize the java heap space.. i can only use 64MB of heap.. no matter how much RAM is available.